# .toggle, make div appear slowly jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, toggle

I have a div called #scrollbox, that appears when my scroll position is more than 170.
How can I make the div to appear slowly with .toggle. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    $("#scrollbox").toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 170);
});
});
```

Comment: You can use `fadeToggle`/`slideToggle` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using .toggle() I believe you use the .fadeIn(speed in ms) function.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 170)
    $("#scrollbox").fadeIn(250);
else
    $('#scrollbox').fadeOut(250);
```

The above effect may or may not be achievable using the .fadeToggle() function.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `fadeIn()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 170)){
           $("#scrollbox").fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
});
```